# Облачный хостинг для фреймворков на Python

Tags: python, flask, tornado, облако

Собираюсь испробовать сразу несколько фреймворков на питоне (Flask, Pyramid, Tornado и др.) в учебных целях. Будет ли облачный хостинг для таких проектов оптимальным решением?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если коротко, то да, будет.

В чём преимущества облаков над VDS? На облаках вы платите только за то, что используете(реально, чуть по-другому). Т.е. если на ваш сайт никто не зашёл, то вы ничего не заплатите. Если же на ваш сайт, внезапно, зашло 100,000 пользователей, то облако просто "растянется", в отличие, от VDS. И на облаках, как правило, не надо ничего настраивать(но есть IaaS).

У VDS же есть другое преимущество: если на ваш сайт стабильно заходит 20k человек в день, то это может оказаться значительно дешевле облаков. Или, на облака не всегда можно установить какие-нибудь специфичные штуки.

Ну а теперь к вопросу: если вы будете пробовать, то высокой посещаемости вы вряд ли дождётесь, и на облаках, как правило, есть бесплатные тарифы. Какие есть:

- Google AppEngine. Странно, что никто его не упомянул. Есть нереляционная БД, 500Мб под скрипты, предустановленный Django. Легко работать. Для бесплатного, имхо, великолепен.
- Amazon. Тоже мощная штука, чуток более сложная в управлении, чем GAE. [Здес](http://habrahabr.ru/post/117146/)ь есть сравнение Amazon'а с GAE
- Heroku. По сравнению с предыдущими, как-то, имхо, не смотрится на бесплатных тарифах, т.к. ограничения очень большие(кажется, 50Мб под скрипты, 20 Мб на MongoDB). Единственный плюс -- куча расширений, многие с бесплатными тарифами.

p.s. А почему вы не хотите запустить локальный сервер?

Comment: спасибо! На локальной машине конечно буду запускать, но хочу посмотреть, как будут работать проекты на разных фреймворках в "боевых" условиях)

Comment: > В чём преимущества облаков над VDS? На облаках вы платите только за то, что используете
Heroku это расскажите, ага. «Облачный» хостинг — обычный маркетинговый баззворд и не более того. По факту же, никаких технических отличий от «классических» shared hosting или VPS нету. Хостеры сто лет как руками и автоматом прозрачно мигрировали виртуалки с хоста на хост. И гибкие тарифы очень давно существуют с различными опциями (в общем-то, со времен появления первых панелей для shared-хостинга).

Comment: Я с Heroku не дружу, т.к. их бесплатные тарифы мне не нравятся. 

"На облаках вы платите только за то, что используете"

Я сделал оговорку, что это в идеале. Но, например, GAE --, если не смотреть на доп. наценку, то там плата только за ресурсы.

На моём хостинге биллинга даже по использованному трафику нет. И плата фиксированная.

Answer (score 2):

Используйте бесплатный тариф от [AWS](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/)

Этого с головой хватит.

Но я не вижу проблемы использовать все это на своем компьютере, или в виртуальной машине.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте Heroku. 1 web worker и 5Mb MySQL будет бесплатно.

Answer (score 1):

Кажется я понял, когда нужно облако, а когда VDS. Облако хорошо подходит тогда, когда есть определенная посещаемость, нагрузка и их сложно планировать, т.е. заранее не знаешь, сколько брать памяти, мощностей процессора итд. Облачный хостинг хорошо подойдет для быстрорастущих стартапов, т.к. можно быстро расширить инфраструктуру при необходимости и платить только за использованные ресурсы.

Если же нужно поставить что-то нестандартное, в качестве эксперимента, или для проектов больших мощностей не требуется, то тогда лучше VDS.

Я прав?

Comment: Да, правильно. Советую просто локально все настроить, или поднять виртуальную машину с линуксом

Comment: Ну как сказать...

У того же кейвеба (который обычные VPS) мне доводилось просить их добавить памяти на OpenVZ'шный VPS. Доплатил разницу в тарифах, виртуалку ребутнули (чтобы /proc/meminfo обновился, хе-хе, так-то аллокатор и без ребута все понимает), и — voilà — вот она, память.

Аналогично памяти, подкрутить на Xen'е процессор через `xm sched-credit` — дело ерундовое.

Вот такое вот облако.